How to remove “Add New Address” button from checkout page in Magento 2.4.6-p3?
I am working on customizing the checkout page in Magento 2.4.6-p3. I was able to remove the shipping and billing address fields using the following XML configuration:
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>

However, I am unable to remove the “Add New Address” button from the checkout page using this method.
Could someone guide me on how to remove the “Add New Address” button from the checkout page? Any help would be appreciated. We

add a screenshot (also enable template path hints and block info so that you can identify where that is coming from)
